# Responding to a tricky situation in a meeting

Tags: employer-relations, employees

---

Editor's note: This question is difficult to understand, so I am leaving the original text of the question below rather than erasing it, in case I have missed a detail and am not properly rewriting the question.  I'm also writing this edit from my perspective rather than OP's perspective.

In this question, there is a client company, C, and 2 contracting companies, A and B, who have contracting relationships with C.  OP is an employee of A, contracting with C.

OP works on a team whose scrum master, X, is an employee of B (it seems X has some amount of authority on this team beyond simply being the scrum master).  X has (seemingly arbitrarily) divided the team in half, and OP has named those 2 halves of the team C and D (not to be confused with company C).  X has assigned certain tasks to team C and others to team D.  OP is a member of team D.

OP was on a client call (I presume a client of company C, not a client of companies A and B, that being C itself) with X and the rest of team D to discuss some project matters.  He asked X and the client during the call if he could invite 2 other employees of company A, E and F, who are members of team C, to the call, so that they can "learn and grow" (for no business purpose).  X said absolutely not; they are irrelevant to the discussion.  X said that even though OP, E, and F, are all employees of company A, at company C they are on different teams and each team has their own purpose, so only team D should be in this call.

OP feels like X's response was belittling and rude and made him feel silly in front of the client.

OP replied to X by saying "fine".

What feedback do we have on how OP could have better handled this situation?

---

**Original question:**

Company A and B has contractors to a client named C. B has four employees already working for C, has been doing for around 3 years and B also has a scrum master(very senior) who kind of handles the daily scrum call where A and B are part of. Mr X(scrum master) is very good in handling scrum calls and the clients

Note that I am part of company A and we have 3 employees who joined just 3 months back.Mr X who is the scrum master has divided the whole team into two(say C and D). Both teams have employees from both A and B.

The team was divided by Mr X into C and D one week back. Now There is a call related to a task that came up and Mr x has asked all the team from D to join. Myself just asked to client(in a call where Mr x is also part of) if we can include mr e and f(my company A employees who are part of C team) and I never mentioned about anything on company. I was kind of just asking so that we all can understand as a team(A) what is going on(we all are new) and grow

Mr x without even giving an opportunity for the client to reply in the call, said "we need to work as a team D and they are part of C. I should not think about company A and B. Mr x understands that company A management wants everyone from A may want to work/understand as a team but we work as a team for the client."

Note that I never mentioned about company name and my management and just mentioned names of e and f. Recently the team was divided into C and D. Tasks are common and overlaps to both the teams.

I was put infront of client like I told something very wrong and he replied to me like I was at fault.

I just replied "fine".

Please let me know your thoughts? How do i handle such situation?

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand, and is made worse by many grammatical errors throughout the question.  I tried to clean it up myself but frankly I have no idea what is being asked.

Comment: Without some sort of diagram, I have completely lost track of who is who here.

Comment: Team D contains workers from both companies/both prior teams A&B. What is special with team D? If D all attend, then both companies get the information needed and can propagate that info to the rest of the companies team in team C. Perhaps this is why Mr X did not want both C&D to attend?

Comment: Note that part of the definition of a scrum meeting is that it is held by and for those _actively_  involved (see the original Scrum book's analogy of of Pigs vs Chickens).  The customer rep, as someone setting the spec, is arguably a pig, at least a chicken. Folks from another team, even if interested, are neither Committed nor Involved and don't belong in a scrum meeting. If you want to keep them informed, at this level of detail, take minutes and (assuming no confidentiality issues) pass them a copy of those... but all they should normally expect is a summary, if that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing my best to try to understand the question: Company C (the client) has contracting arrangements with 2 contracting companies, A and B.  You are an employee of A.  The scrum master (X) for this particular team is an employee of B.  The team was split in half by X into C and D.

At this point I'm going to stop and say that either X has split the teams or he hasn't (and either he has the authority to do so, or he doesn't).  If X has split the teams, then he can be the scrum master for both teams, and the 2 teams can work closely together, but each team should have their own responsibilities.  There should be no projects that are worked on by both teams (in that the teams should not share tickets; C should have their own tickets, and D should have their own tickets, and X should assign tickets to C or D).  Furthermore, C and D should each have their own team lead or manager who the team members report to, and ideally those 2 people are not the same person (it sounds like they are the same person and that person is X).

Continuing on, you were in a client call with X and team D related to a project that team D is working on.  You wanted to ask X if you could include team C members, and company A employees, E and F into the call.

Pausing here for a moment, this is not your call to make.  E and F are not part of D, therefore their involvement in the call is not relevant to the project.  This project is team D's project, not team C's project and therefore E and F's presence is irrelevant.  E and F have their own team C work to work on, they don't need to be in your call.  The answer to your question is **no**.  Don't invite everyone and their cousin to your calls.  Calls are best when the fewest, most knowledgeable people are in the call.  This goes double for client calls where you're supposed to be showing the client how smart you are and how great your service is; you don't want to include new people who don't know anything and are unrelated to the project without a good reason.

Continuing on, X gave you the same answer to your question as I did; he said it doesn't matter if E and F are part of company A; what matters is that this call is a team D matter and E and F are not team D members, so they are irrelevant and no you can't invite them.  The fact that you and they are all from company A is irrelevant.  He was correct in this statement.  Unless you have a specific reason why E and F should be on the call, they should not be on the call.  Simply that you and they are contractors from the same contracting company is not sufficiently relevant.  The fact that some tasks overlap teams is also irrelevant, unless those specific tasks that overlap teams are the ones being discussed in this client call, and E and F are the ones working on those tasks in team C.

Simply put, you did "tell" (say) something very wrong in front of the client and you were at fault.  You made yourself look stupid to X and to the client and you made company A look like they hire stupid people because you are a company A employee.  As an employee of company C, and even more as a contracting representative of company A, don't do this.

Given the situation above, "fine" was not the correct response.  "Fine" means "I think you're wrong but I won't push the issue".  X is not the one who is wrong here, you are.  You should say "I understand", and you should learn from this experience as to why it is not proper for E and F to be a part of this call.  If you do not understand why, you should discuss it with X (in private, not in front of coworkers, and **definitely** not in front of clients) and he can explain to you in depth.

Simply put, the thing to take away from this experience and learn is that calls, and especially client calls, are the best when there are the fewest people.  The reason is, the more people on a call, the more people are talking, and the more time you take to accomplish anything.  Especially when the people are unrelated, then they will ask unrelated (or in worst case, outright stupid) questions and waste time.  You don't want to do this, especially in front of a client.  If you want to ask if a person should be included on a call, the first thing to think about is "what is this person contributing to this call?  What information do they have that is necessary to discuss in this call, and this call specifically (as opposed to a different call with the same people)?".  If the people you want to invite are not directly contributing to the content or context of the call in any meaningful way, you should not even ask the question if you can invite them.

Comment: The OP might want to reread the book that defined the scrum process. Not because it needs to be followed absolutely, but because it spells out very clearly why meetings should be shrestricted to the people directly involved in the topic that meeting is

Answer (score 2):

Okay - on the second re-read of your question, I think I understand:

In short - someone from another company who is contracted by the same company that you contract to, is the Scrum Master/senior person and has split the pool of contractors into 2 groups *at the company you both contract to* - and when you asked if you could include people from your company (who are part of the *other* team) - the Scrum master told you that he didn't want you thinking in terms of your company, but in terms of the teams he's put you in.

I don't see an issue with this, to be honest. It may have been blunt and it may have been in front of the client - but given that you've indicated that the Scrum Master is:

1: Very good at his role and
2: Senior in his role

There's a good reason to presume that he has split the teams in the way that he has for a reason, based on the strengths of each person.

Now, you may have had a reason for wanting to pull people in who are from your parent company, but not the same team - but here's the issue:

That has the perception of bias/favoritism - and the Scrum Master shot that down very quickly *so that he can run the team without his decision making being perceived as being biased*.

If you believe he's wrong on this - how I would approach it would be to have a private meeting and outline exactly what skills your colleagues bring to the table on that specific issue and why it is in your client's best interest to do that. Let him make the call and then abide by the decision.

To do anything else is to put him in a situation where it will ultimately undermine his authority and make him 'pick sides' - which is the worst thing to happen.

Comment: i get it and understand

Answer (score 1):

> X said absolutely not; they are irrelevant to the discussion. X said
> that even though OP, E, and F, are all employees of company A, at
> company C they are on different teams and each team has their own
> purpose, so only team D should be in this call.

That sounds perfectly acceptable. I see no rudeness or belittling in those words.

> OP replied to X by saying "fine".

That sounds perfectly acceptable.

I see no problem here that needs to be solved. But I do sense some sour grapes on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be embarrassed in front of a client, don't ask questions in front of the client whose answer might embarrass you. Wait and ask them later.

No opinion on the rest; even in the edited down version it's more tangled that I want to deal with right now.